# I want to have multiple click events that start timers occuring at the same time is this possible? If so how?

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I'm in the middle of writing my first real program and i can't seem to find a solution to this. I want to be able to click multiple labels at different times with out stopping previous labels when a new one is clicked. At first this seemed a simple problem to me but after reading i believe its more involved then i thought. Will asynchronous code solve my problem here? If not, what will? Btw code compiles and works great besides my obvious problem.

```
from Tkinter import *
import os
import time


class League_Jungle_Timer(Frame):

  def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.master.title("Jungle Timer by BabyAchilles")                                   # initializes window
        self.master.geometry("550x300")

        self.pack(expand = YES, fill = BOTH)  


        self.Label1 = Label(self)
        self.Label1 = Label(text = "Blue Buff")             #-------------->   #Start Tkinter GUI Labels                     
        self.Label1.pack()


        self.Label2 = Label(self)
        self.Label2 = Label(self, text = "Red Buff")
        self.Label2.pack()

        self.Label3=Label(self)
        self.Label3=Label(self, text = "Dragon",font=("Helvetica", 16))
        self.Label3.pack()

        self.Button1 = Button(self)         #-------------->          #Start Tkinter GUI Buttons
        self.Button1["text"] = "Blue Buff"
        self.Button1["fg"]   = "Blue"
        self.Button1["command"] = self.label_clicked

        self.Button1.pack({"side": "left"})

        self.Button2 = Button(self)
        self.Button2["text"] = "Red Buff"
        self.Button2["fg"] = "Red"
        self.Button2["command"] = self.my_timeRB

        self.Button2.pack({"side":"right"}) 
        self.Button2.pack(padx=50)

        self.Button3 = Button(self)
        self.Button3["text"] = " Dragon "
        self.Button3["fg"] = "Pink"
        self.Button3["bg"] = "Purple"
        self.Button3["command"] = self.my_timeDrag

        self.Button3.pack(side="bottom",pady=50)

        self.Quit = Button(self)
        self.Quit["text"] = "Quit"
        self.Quit["command"] = self.destroy

        self.Quit.pack()

        self.Label1.bind("<Button-1>", self.label_clicked)
        self.Label2.bind("<Button-3>", self.label2_clicked)
        self.Label3.bind("<Double-Button-1>",self.label3_clicked)
##########################################################################    
  def my_timeDrag(self):  # creates a timer starting at 5 min , counts down to 0 then repeats
    min_m = 5
    sec = 59
    while sec <=60:
      self.Label3.configure(text="{0}:{1:02}".format(min_m, sec))
      self.Label3.update()
      os.system('cls')
      print min_m, "Minutes", sec, "Seconds"
      time.sleep(1)
      sec -= 1
      if    sec == 0:
            min_m -= 1
            sec = 59
      elif  min_m == 0:
            min_m = 5
##########################################################################################

  def my_timeBB(self):  # creates a timer starting at 5 min , counts down to 0 then repeats
    min_m = 4
    sec = 59
    while sec <=60:
      self.Label1.configure(text="{0}:{1:02}".format(min_m,sec))
      self.Label1.update()
      os.system('cls')
      print min_m, "Minutes", sec, "Seconds"
      time.sleep(1)
      sec -= 1
      if   sec == 0:
           min_m -= 1
           sec = 59
      elif min_m == 0:
           min_m = 4


#######################################################   
  def my_timeRB(self):  # creates a timer starting at 5 min , counts down to 0 then repeats
    _min = 4
    sec = 59
    while sec <=60:
      self.Label2.configure(text="{0}:{1:02}".format(_min,sec))
      self.Label2.update()
      os.system('cls')
      print _min, "Minutes", sec, "Seconds"
      time.sleep(1)
      sec -= 1
      if    sec == 0:
            _min -= 1
            sec = 59
      elif  _min == 0:
            _min = 4

##############################################################
  def label_clicked(self, event):
    self.Label1.configure(self.my_timeBB())
    self.Label1.update()
  def label2_clicked(self, event):
    self.Label2.configure(self.my_timeRB())
    self.Label2.update()                     
  def label3_clicked(self, even):
    self.Label3.configure(self.my_timeDrag())
    self.Label3.update()        



League_Jungle_Timer().mainloop()
```

Comment: You could use `tk.after()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tk.after()` to get this.

With `after(1000, function_name)` you run some (small) function after 1000 ms and it will not stop other functions (if you don't use `time.sleep`). And this function can user `after()` to run itself again.

```
from Tkinter import *
import os
import time

class League_Jungle_Timer(Frame):

    def __init__(self):
        Frame.__init__(self)

        # initializes window
        self.master.title("Jungle Timer by BabyAchilles")
        self.master.geometry("550x300")

        self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)  

        # Start Tkinter GUI Labels
        self.label1 = Label(self, text="Blue Buff")                     
        self.label1.pack()


        self.label2 = Label(self, text="Red Buff")
        self.label2.pack()

        self.label3=Label(self, text="Dragon", font=("Helvetica", 16))
        self.label3.pack()

        # Start Tkinter GUI Buttons
        self.Button1 = Button(self, text="Blue Buff", fg="Blue", command=self.my_timeBB)
        self.Button1.pack(side="left")

        self.Button2 = Button(self, text="Red Buff", fg="Red", command=self.my_timeRB)
        self.Button2.pack(side="right", padx=50)

        self.Button3 = Button(self, text=" Dragon ", fg="Pink", bg="Purple", command=self.my_timeDrag)
        self.Button3.pack(side="bottom",pady=50)

        self.Quit = Button(self, text="Quit", command=self.destroy)
        self.Quit.pack()

        self.label1.bind("<Button-1>", self.label_clicked)
        self.label2.bind("<Button-3>", self.label2_clicked)
        self.label3.bind("<Double-Button-1>",self.label3_clicked)

        self.timer_id_DR = None
        self.timer_id_RB = None
        self.timer_id_BB = None

    #######################################################   
    # creates a timer starting at 5 min , counts down to 0 then repeats

    def my_timeDrag(self):
        self.my_timeDrag_time = [4, 59]
        if self.timer_id_DR:
            self.after_cancel(self.timer_id_DR)
            self.timer_id_DR = None
        self.my_timeDrag_after()

    def my_timeDrag_after(self):
        m, s = self.my_timeDrag_time
        self.label3.configure(text="{0}:{1:02}".format(m, s))
        self.label3.update()
        #os.system('cls')
        print "DR", m, "Minutes", s, "Seconds"

        s -= 1
        if s == 0:
           m -= 1
           s = 59
        elif m == 0:
           m = 5

        self.my_timeDrag_time = [m, s]

        self.timer_id_DR = self.after(1000, self.my_timeDrag_after)

    #######################################################   
    # creates a timer starting at 5 min , counts down to 0 then repeats

    def my_timeBB(self):
        self.my_timeBB_time = [4, 59]
        if self.timer_id_BB:
            self.after_cancel(self.timer_id_BB)
            self.timer_id_BB = None        
        self.my_timeBB_after()

    def my_timeBB_after(self):
        m, s = self.my_timeBB_time
        self.label1.configure(text="{0}:{1:02}".format(m, s))
        self.label1.update()
        #os.system('cls')
        print "BB", m, "Minutes", s, "Seconds"

        s -= 1
        if s == 0:
           m -= 1
           s = 59
        elif m == 0:
           m = 5

        self.my_timeBB_time = [m, s]

        self.timer_id_BB = self.after(1000, self.my_timeBB_after)

    #######################################################   

    def my_timeRB(self):
        self.my_timeRB_time = [4, 59]
        #if self.timer_id_RB:
        self.after_cancel(self.timer_id_RB)
        #self.timer_id_RB = None         
        self.my_timeRB_after()

    def my_timeRB_after(self):
        m, s = self.my_timeRB_time
        self.label2.configure(text="{0}:{1:02}".format(m, s))
        self.label2.update()
        #os.system('cls')
        print "RB", m, "Minutes", s, "Seconds"

        s -= 1
        if s == 0:
           m -= 1
           s = 59
        elif m == 0:
           m = 5

        self.my_timeRB_time = [m, s]

        self.timer_id_BB = self.after(1000, self.my_timeRB_after)

    #######################################################   

    def label_clicked(self, event):
        self.label1.configure(self.my_timeBB())
        self.label1.update()
    def label2_clicked(self, event):
        self.label2.configure(self.my_timeRB())
        self.label2.update()                     
    def label3_clicked(self, even):
        self.label3.configure(self.my_timeDrag())
        self.label3.update()        

##############################################################

League_Jungle_Timer().mainloop()
```

Comment: So i just notice an issue with this, the time needs to be able to be reset but with this code resetting it throws off the timing and it gets progressively worse the more its clicked

Comment: In current version every click runs another `after()`. You need `timer_id = after()` and then you can kill it `after_cancel(timer_id)`

Comment: Okay , i see so are "id" and "cancel" built in attributes or something?

Comment: `timer_id` is only my own variable to keep value returned by `after()` - it string so you can print it. `after_cancel()` is Tkinter function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56740/discussion-between-achilles-and-furas).

Answer (score 0):

The fix is pretty easy, but a little involved.

You need to use python's multithreading and queue libraries.

First off you want to import:

```
import threading
import Queue
```

Then set up the threading class:

```
class ThreadedClient(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, queue, fcn):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.fcn = fcn
    def run(self)
        time.sleep(1)
        self.queue.put(self.fcn())
```

Then, inside of your `League_Jungle_Timer` class, add two functions. `spawnthread` sets up the threading, starts it, and then calls `periodiccall` which lets the main loop and any "concurrent" functions.

```
def spawnthread(self, fcn):
    self.thread = ThreadedClient1(self.queue, fcn)
    self.thread.start()
    self.periodiccall(thread)

def periodiccall(self):
    if self.thread.is_alive():
        self.after(100, self.periodiccall)
```

Add this line to `League_Jungle_Timer`'s init method to set up the queue:

```
self.queue = Queue.Queue()
```

To use, call with `lambda: self.spawnthread(self.my_timeBB())` or whatever other function you'd like to call. Use that expression as a button callback or in the label configs.

Comment: Yeah! Let me know if there are any problems. I adapted from some old code of mine (I had this same problem about a year ago) so it might be a little different.

Comment: Quick question, am i adding self.queue = Queue.Queue() to init method for ThreadedCLient class or my League_Jungle_Timer class? Im assuming the ladder.

Comment: You assumed correctly! Editing answer to be more clear.

Comment: Im messing around with it now i have it mostly adapted but i keep getting an invalid syntax error for the spawnthread function hmmm

Comment: seems fine to me can't find any obvious syntax errors and there isn't much in the function....idk. Also, what does lambda do?

Comment: Still nice to know though i always appreciate the info and its nice to know how to do things multiple ways!

Comment: Thanks @BryanOakley. Multithreading has worked for me in the past but yeah, it is basically overkill.